# How to remove duplicate words from the string in PHP

Tags: php, string, duplicates

I have following string with repeated words like:

```
$string = 'This is titleThis is titleThis is Title';
```

Now I want to remove duplicate words `This is titleThis is Title` as repeated for two times in my string.

I am looking for this output: `This is title`.

I have tried with `implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $string)))` but not getting luck.

Comment: `preg_replace("/^(.+)\1+$/","$1",$string);` perhaps? Your requirements are vague.

Comment: What about "It is what it is"? Will you want to remove the second "it" and/or "is"?

Comment: explode the string on a space instead of a `,`. I dont see any `,` in your string.

Comment: I am getting duplicate words from the database like `This is titleThis is titleThis is Title` and I want to remove the duplicate words and want to display like `This is title`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this one code. Explode the string on a `space` instead of a `,`

```
<?php
$string = 'This is titleThis is titleThis is Title';

echo implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', $string)));
```

Comment: After using your code I am getting this output: `This is titleThis Title` but I want like `This is title` result.

Comment: I am trying but issue arrived for anothers way

Comment: Can you please help on this. Thanks :)